# Set a void function inside another function

Tags: c++

I am trying to do set a void function in c++ inside another void. I was instructed to use this non-functioning code:

```
void function() {
    log("Original function")
}
int main(){
function = []()
    { 
        log("New Function");
    };
}
```

and get this :

> error: invalid use of member function ‘void function()’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?).

Can anyone help? Is this even possible and if not then can anyone provide an alternative? All help is approved.

Comment: why are you trying to do this? You cannot assign to a function like that. `auto function = []()...`would work. What is the aim?

Comment: You can achieve something like this using function pointers or `std::function`. But what are you trying to achieve? What problem exactly are you hoping to solve?

Comment: Much like if you had a hardcoded a constant like `42` in your code that you wanted to be able to change at runtime you would need to store the value `42` in a _variable_, and then refactor your code to refer to the variable instead of the literal hardcoded `42`.  You have to do the same thing with your function.  If you want to change which function will be called at runtime, then you'll need a variable. `std::function<void()>` would be a reasonable type for such a variable which could be assigned either `function` or your lambda function, but the variable's name shouldn't be `function` again.

Comment: "set a void function in c++ inside another void" This doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Perhaps you could quote your assignment verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `function` to be a function pointer, not a function.
So maybe something a little like this:

```
void (*function)();

int main(){
function = []()
    {
        log("New Function");
    };
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... and a little [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YTx9afeox)

Answer (score 1):

Function definitions cannot be changed at runtime like this, so you will need to use some sort rebindable object that is invocable instead.

If your lambda is never going to capture a value, then you can use function pointers for this purpose -- since a non-capturing lambda can be converted to a function pointer. For example:

```cpp
using function_t = void(*)();

void function_default() { 
    log("Original function");
}

function_t function = &function_default;

int main() {
    function = []{
        log("New Function");
    };
}
```

<kbd>[Try it Online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sKEnszMxe)</kbd>

However, be aware that as soon as you want to capture data in that lambda, this will not work. At which point you'll be better off using something like [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) which can work with any invocable object:

```cpp
using function_t = std::function<void()>;

void function_default() { 
    log("Original function");
}

function_t function = &function_default;

int main() {
    int some_value = 5;
    function = [=]{
        log("New Function with value = " + std::to_string(some_value));
    };
}
```

<kbd>[Try it Online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5MYrv6q6x)</kbd>

Comment: I have a problem. When in header file I get this error that I don't in cpp file.
```
error: cannot convert ‘void (className::*)()’ to ‘function_t’ {aka ‘void (*)()’} in initialization
```

Comment: Fixed the issue using extern. Thanks so much for the help. Now I can continue what I set out for.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, you can do this, but it will require the usage of a lambda function:

```
void main()
{
    auto func = []()-> void // Note: This is a lambda function.
    {
         // Code...
    };
    // If you want to run "func" call it in your void, if not, leave it uncalled.
    func();
}
```

For more information on lambdas, I'll provide a link [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).